# configure https endpoint in python opentelemetry library

Tags: python, open-telemetry

i
I have the following code that tries to send opentelemetry traces to an https OTLP endpoint. However, it generates a certificate verification error. I understand that I need to configure a certificate but don't know how. I have succeeded to generate a certificate, but don't know how to configure it in the python library.

```
from opentelemetry import trace
# from opentelemetry.exporter.jaeger.thrift import JaegerExporter
from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.http.trace_exporter import OTLPSpanExporter
#from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.grpc.trace_exporter import OTLPSpanExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import SERVICE_NAME, Resource
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor

...

resource = Resource(attributes={
        SERVICE_NAME: "demo"
    })
    provider = TracerProvider(resource=resource)
    processor = BatchSpanProcessor(OTLPSpanExporter(endpoint="<endpointhost>/v1/traces", insecure=True))
    provider.add_span_processor(processor)
    trace.set_tracer_provider(provider)
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Can you also paste the exact error too?

Answer (score 1):

I think, I managed to resolve the problem by providing a certificate file like below

```
    processor = BatchSpanProcessor(OTLPSpanExporter(endpoint="<ENDPOINTHOST>/v1/traces", certificate_file='CERTIFICATE FILE'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).